# How to configure Gridsome to generate thousands of product pages using API's to insert the data into static site template?

Tags: vue.js, templates, seo, static-site, gridsome

I am looking to utilize a static site generator framework to work with Vue in order to generate static pages with product info, however we need to create thousands of pages with a different product for each page, we hope to make api calls to retrieve data and then fill in our templates with the different data and pictures for each product, the hope is it boost our search results for part #'s and bring in more business, does Gridsome do this? If so, how do I go about setting up this functionality? Or is Gridsome not the best option for this? I am open to exploring different frameworks but we would like to use Vue still for UI development though we are open to just plain html, css, and vanilla javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Gridsome was designed to handle exactly your situation. From [gridsome.org](https://gridsome.org):

You can make API calls to retrieve the data:

> Gridsome makes it painlessly easy to build Jamstack websites using data from multiple sources such as Content API's, Headless CMSs, and other web services.

It's SEO-friendly to boost your search results:

> Gridsome sites load as static HTML before they hydrate into fully Vue.js-powered SPAs. This makes it possible for search engines to be able to crawl content and give better SEO ranking, and still have all the power of Vue.js.

A good next step might be to check out the various [starter templates](https://gridsome.org/starters/) on the Gridsome website.